# The least complex animals with ability to dream

Tags: zoology, sleep, dreaming

People can dream, dogs can dream, cats probably too when they are sleeping.

What about other creatures?

Can a bird dream?

Do rats have dreams?

Are there any studies about that kind of thing? What is the most simple organism that have brain structures that allow them dreaming during the sleep?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted ?

Comment: Yes why has it been downvoted? at least comment feedback to suggest improvement...

Answer (score 4):

Since mammals all share the same neural structures it is quite likely that most non human species dream, but as yet, the simplest animal I could find that has been scientifically demonstrated to dream is the rat, as proven by Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT).

MIT not only established that rat were capable of dreaming about the events they had experienced while awake, but that the content of the dreams could be manipulated with audio cues the rats had been trained to respond with in a specific way.

Sources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain#Mammals

http://web.mit.edu/newsoffice/2012/neuroscientists-achieve-dream-engineering-0902.html

Answer (score 4):

At least [one study from University of Chicago](http://www.uchospitals.edu/news/2000/20001027-dreamsong.html) showed that birds dream...about singing.